# Google Chrome's caching mechanism of static resources varies from other browsers. Is it right?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, firefox, caching, http-caching

**Setup:**

I used nginx server. I experimented with two different sets of header configuration.

**1. Expires header only.

2. Expires and Last Modified header**

I had the done the following in all the browsers,

1. Clear the cache.Access the page (or Hard reload). Now , all the resources are freshly downloaded. The page downloads only one JS file.
2. Do a soft reload. (Cmd + R)

When the soft reload is done,

**Case 1:Expires header only**

1.Chrome (v55) serves from disk/memory cache with Status 200.It does not fetch resource from the server.

2.Firefox (v51) sends a request and downloads the resource each time with Status 200. When the resource has only one expires header, firefox and other browsers always downloads the resource.

**Case 2: Expires and Last Modified header**

1.Chrome again serves from disk/memory cache with Status 200. It does not fetch resource from the server.

2.Firefox and Other browsers always sends a **'If-modified-since'** header to the server, depending on the header, the server sends either 200 and the resource or 304 Not modified.

The problem with other browsers approach is that , they always send a request for a resource to check it's freshness. Let's say there are 40 static resources, each time i hit a reload the browser will send a request.
This causes increase usage of bandwidth, number of requests to the server.

Which approach is good?

**P.S.** In chrome ,when u have only 'Last Modified header', it sends a request for 304 Not Modified. But with expires and Last modified, it always serves from cache.